# How can I translate this run docker command into docker-compose?

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose

Trying to setup Redis from this image [Redismod](https://hub.docker.com/r/redislabs/redismod) and struggle to translate the following code into docker-compose

```
$ docker run \
  -p 6379:6379 \
  -v /home/user/data:/data \
  -v /home/user/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf \
  redislabs/redismod \
  /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
```

What I have done till now:

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  redis:
    image: "redislabs/redismod"
    container_name: 'redis-local'
    hostname: 'redis-local'
    volumes_from: 
      - redis_data:/data
      - ./redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
    args:
      - /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
volumes: 
  redis_data:
```

But I get the following error `ERROR: Service "redis" mounts volumes from "redis_data", which is not the name of a service or container.` obviously because I didn't pass the last line `/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf`

And second question, how do I translate `--loadmodule` and `--dir` from below, these aren't Redis command:

```
$ docker run \
  -p 6379:6379 \
  -v /home/user/data:/data \
  redislabs/redismod \
  --loadmodule /usr/lib/redis/modules/rebloom.so \
  --dir /data
```

**UPDATE**
I changed my docker-compose.yml file to the following and it started to work, but it seems that Redis doesn't see the `redis.conf` file and continue to run in default mode, what I do wrong?

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  redis:
    image: "redislabs/redismod"
    container_name: 'redis-local'
    hostname: 'redis-local'
    volumes: 
      - redis_data:/data
      - ./redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
    build: 
      context: .
      args:
        - /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first error was because you used `volumes_from` instead of `volumes`. The first one is intended to get the volumes configuration from an existing container. The second one to define the volumes. In your last version `redis_data` is a docker volume and `redis.conf` is a bind mount. Your second problem is that you are using `build` and `args` that are intended to be used for building images but looks like you wanted to run a command.

Try:

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  redis:
    image: "redislabs/redismod"
    container_name: 'redis-local'
    hostname: 'redis-local'
    volumes: 
      - redis_data:/data
      - ./redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
    command: usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```

For more info about volumes, bind mounts and docker compose reference see:

- https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/
- https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/
- https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#command